# AlertController doesn't save textField text on save, only edit

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an alertController with a textField. The user enters their data into the textField and hits "set". It should then create the item and save the text entered as my attribute it's set to. However, upon creating the item the textField passes nil. It's not saved until the item is reopened and saved again (prompting the alertController to request data in the textField). Why is it not saving it the first time?

saveButton pressed:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (item?.slminqty == nil) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Minimun Qty.", message: "Please set minimun qty. for pantry.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Minimun Qty."
        textField.keyboardType = .NumbersAndPunctuation
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {saveitem}()))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Set", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(action) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0].text!
        self.item?.slminqty = textField

       self.saveitem(self)}))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{

        if item != nil {
            edititems()

        } else {
            createitems()
        }
        print(item?.slminqty)

        dismissVC()
    }

    }
```

Save function:

```
func saveitem(sender: AnyObject) {

    if item != nil {
        edititems()

    } else {
        createitems()
    }
    print(item?.slminqty)

    dismissVC()
}
```

Create function:

```
func createitems() {

    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: moc)

    let item = List(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    item.slitem = slitem.text
    item.sldesc = sldesc.text
    item.slqty = slqty.text
    item.slprice = slprice.text
    item.slist = true
    item.slcross = false

    if slitem.text == nil{
        createitems()

    }else{
        edititems()
    }

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch _ {
        return
    }
}
```

Edit function:

```
func edititems() {
    item?.slitem = slitem.text!
    item?.sldesc = sldesc.text!
    item?.slqty = slqty.text!
    item?.slprice = slprice.text!

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        return
    }
}
```

If both of the create and edit are the same (with the exception of slcross and slist) why won't it save the data when the item is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** please see my [pull reqest](https://github.com/barkerdrmmr182/Listacular/pull/1), I have made some changes to your code. along with some comments.

I think the problem in this line :

```
 self.item?.slminqty = textField
```

`self.item` might be nil. you should make sure first item is not nil.

you may try to create item if this is nil. like:

```
if self.item == nil {
   //create item. 
   self.acreateItems()
   // after creating the item just test its value.
    print("item was nil so we just created it.\nIts value not is \(self.item)")
}
self.item?.slminqty = textField
```

Comment: How in the world do I do that? This is the only way i've gotten the code to work so far. I have no idea how to make sure item isn't nil. I don't understand why it works for editing the item but not in the creation of it?Could you please explain it a little further, and what I should be doing for it to work?

Comment: I'm sorry. That still has the same effect as not having the "if" statement. It prints "item was nil so we just created it." but still returns nil for slminqty on the creation but returns it correctly upon editing.

Comment: IT seems that `createItems()` doesn't realy update `self.item`. I'm not sure how you create item. but you should be able to create one inside this if.
I was right about the item is nil which was th main problem. you just want to cteate item.

Comment: I believe createitems() is updating self.item because it creates everything  minus the item.slminqty. Once the "set" button is pressed it passes it back to the saveitem() function which determines if item is nil or not. Because item was nil it passes to createitem() and saves item.attributes. Which it does, except for item.slminqty. Once the item is opened again, item is !=nil so it edits item and updates any changes. However, it updates the item.slminqty at that time and actually returns the inputted value.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, I'm learning this as I go and just want to make sure I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please check the value of the item after creating it. just like in the answer. and let me know. if you need further help. I can give you a hand solving it via team viewer if you like.

Comment: No problem. The value when it's created returns nil. When it's edited after its created it return the value entered. It's as an optional but it still works. I'm not sure what team viewer is. My code is on GitHub, if that would be easier?

Comment: yeah. Github is great. Send me the URL please. FYI, [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) is a program allows you to share your screen with other team members and also has the option to let them have a control to it.

Comment: https://github.com/barkerdrmmr182/Listacular.git ...Oh cool basically remote view. I use remote host viewer to remote into my grandmother's computer when she has an issue. Github will be easier for me though due to work.

Comment: I'm looking at your project right now and adding some comments to it. then I'll send it to you somehow.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I think there is a way to submit a correction on there for me to review and/or accept but I'm really not sure how to do that...google drive always works too, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102416/discussion-between-will-zimmer-and-ismail).